# Telerik Radgrid GridDataItem.DataItem is empty when updating (OnUpdateCommand handler)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

When handling the OnUpdateCommand event on a RadGrid the DataItem is null.

I thought that this would also represent the data item being represented by the row.

The Radgrid is populated from an IList and in the handler the code looks like this...

```
protected void rgAllocatedClients_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        var gridDataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        var client= gridDataItem .DataItem as Client;
        ....
        ....
```

This works find when handling the ItemDataBound event but not when handling the UpdateCommand event. I really need this as in my Client class is the Id of the row I want to handle the update for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by using  GridEditableItem

```
 protected void grdContacts_UpdateCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        string idEditing = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Id"].ToString();
        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        Hashtable newValues = new Hashtable();
// ur code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Grid is in Edit mode befor ethe Update Command, you should cast e.Item to GridEditableItem instead of GridDataItem