# Get name of an object without getting its bits type

Tags: c#

I need to get names of few objects. The names cannot contain their bits (16/32/64). Actaully I do it this way `object.GetType().Name`. When I use int as object (`int.GetType().Name`) it returns int. But when I use uint it returns uint32. I want to get only uint. Is there a better way to do this than String.Replace?

Comment: Why exactly do you want `unit` rather than `uint32`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmm, no, you won't get "int".  Do try to make a minimal effort to post valid repro code.  Words like `int` and `uint` are *keywords* in the C# language.  Translating from the framework type name to the keyword is probably best done with a switch statement.  Or just don't bother since it doesn't matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a type's alias through reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363309/2803565)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telerik Radgrid GridDataItem.DataItem is empty when updating (OnUpdateCommand handler)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803565/telerik-radgrid-griddataitem-dataitem-is-empty-when-updating-onupdatecommand-ha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the compiler services to do so:

```
static string GetFriendlyTypeName<T>()
{
    var csharpCodeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
    var codeType = new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(typeof(T));
    return csharpCodeProvider.GetTypeOutput(codeType);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetFriendlyTypeName<Int32>()); //int
    Console.WriteLine(GetFriendlyTypeName<UInt32>()); //uint
}
```

Comment: but it seems that he want to get type name from an object instance (or variable)

Comment: @S.Serp That would be a piece of cake for any developer, just add `T value` as a parameter to the `GetFriendlyTypeName` method